# Does Catboost JAVA library support prediction for models trained on GPU?

Tags: catboost

I have a few models trained on CPU and GPU (using python). I am using catboost-prediction (version 1.2.2) for generating predictions in java.

I am comparing the predictions generated from python and java libraries.

Models trained on CPU are generating predictions as expected (java and python generating same predictions). But models trained on GPU does not produce the same results.

Does catboost-prediction lib support models trained on GPU for prediction ?

I did not find anything useful really. I am wondering if prediction on GPU models is even supported in caboost java API yet.